# Decoding QR code in photo using Zxing

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, photo

I want to decode some photos with QR code. 
I found this method:

```
public static String readQRCode(String filePath, String charset, Map hintMap) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException {
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
            new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                    ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filePath)))));

    Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap, hintMap);
    return qrCodeResult.getText();
}
```

It's working on pictures like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdWIc.jpg). 
Unfortunately it doesn't work on all images, i.e: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uqvY.jpg). As you see it has poor quality.

```
Error: com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
```

Any ideas, what can I do?

Comment: What do have in your `hintMap`

Comment: @PrerakSola
`String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
  
Map hintMap = new HashMap(); 

hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

System.out.println("Data read from QR Code: "
    + QCRH.readQRCode(filePath2, charset, hintMap));`

Comment: Your second 'poor quality' image doesn't appear to scan at all with Barcode Scanner (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en) even when blocking out the background with a white field. It may be a non-standard QR code format which won't be read by ZXing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Variants).

Comment: @MorrisonChang 
ye i know that but it have to work even with bad quality pictures...

Do you have idea why this method doesn't works on that picture: http://imgur.com/8B547uO ? It works at online scanner https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Comment: Apologies, it looks like by increasing the contrast on http://imgur.com/L3kfW4y I was able to get ZXing to decode. You could apply the same to your images before passing them on to ZXing, at the cost of performance. Handling contrast in a live camera is a different problem.

Comment: @MorrisonChang
Which one application you used to increase contrast? I made my own in C#, it's working ( i mean increasing contrast) but even after that ZXing failed on decoding that picture.

Comment: Did it via the image editor app on my Mac laptop. Here it is: http://imgur.com/a/5OV32 As it I know it is possible it would be a matter of figuring what transformations are appropriate for any test set.